# Granger causality test result depends on whether boot is used or not. Which result should one take?

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I estimated a VAR model and used the Granger-causality test, to interpret the model. I used the `causality` function to check for possible Granger-causality, but I get conflicting results depending on using `boot` or not. I am confused. Which result should I take for interpretation? Variables are stationary and the residuals are all fine: no autocorrelation and homoskedasty. Number of observations used for the VAR model = 65.

```
causality(Var1, cause = "DBIP1ts", boot = FALSE)
```

--> H0 is rejected; p-value is 0.03

```
causality(Var1, cause = "DBIP1ts", boot = TRUE, boot.runs = 1000)
```

--> H0 is not rejected; p-value is 0.14

I am confused. Which result should I take for interpretation?